# My colorbar doesn't show the right colors (Python, matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

I'm stuck trying to get my colorbar to show the same colorspectrum as my scatterplot. Instead of the pink/purple to black spectrum of my colorgraded datapoints, it shows the default colors of a colorbar. I have read multiple other threads on here to no avail, but please alert me to a similar thread, if I have missed something that could solve my problem.

I have made a short code illustrating my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng()
arr = np.arange(7000)
rng.shuffle(arr)
r = np.sqrt(np.random.random(7000))
theta = np.random.uniform(high = 2*np.pi, size = 7000)
X = np.array(r*np.cos(theta))
Y = np.array(r*np.sin(theta))

def values_to_colormap(values):
    values_scale = values/np.max(values)
    (a,) = np.shape(values)
    cmap = values_scale.reshape(a,1)*np.array([[0.6, 0.4, 0.6]])
    return cmap

points_colors = values_to_colormap(arr)

ps = plt.scatter(X,Y, marker = '.', color = points_colors)
plt.colorbar(ps, orientation='horizontal')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show();
```

[image: My resulting plot and colorbar]

Comment: Instead of specifying colors, suggest you use the *c* argument of `scatter`:   `plt.scatter(X, Y, c=arr, marker='.', cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=np.max(arr))`.  That pushes your problem down to making a colormap cmap: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colorbar uses the `cmap` and the `norm` of the scatter plot. In this case,  individual colors are given, and the colorbar falls back to the default colormap ('viridis') and the default norm (as no `vmin` nor `vmax` nor explicit color values are given, 0 and 1 are used).

Your `values_to_colormap` function maps 0 to color `(0, 0, 0)` and the maximum value to `(0.6, 0.4, 0.6)`.  This is equivalent to use a norm with `vmin=0`, `vmax=arr.max()` and a `LinearSegmentedColormap` between the given colors:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

rng = np.random.default_rng()
arr = np.arange(7000)
rng.shuffle(arr)
r = np.sqrt(np.random.random(7000))
theta = np.random.uniform(high=2 * np.pi, size=7000)
X = np.array(r * np.cos(theta))
Y = np.array(r * np.sin(theta))

ps = plt.scatter(X, Y, marker='.', c=arr, vmin=0, vmax=arr.max(),
                 cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', [(0, 0, 0), (0.6, 0.4, 0.6)]))
plt.colorbar(ps, orientation='horizontal')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: Using a LinearSegmentedColormap to generate the colorbar]